# $A \perp B$ and $A+B\perp r\left( 2A+B\right)$ for some continuous function $r$. Is there such a triplet $\left( A,B,r\right) $ with non-constant function $r$? 

Tags: pr.probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be independent continuous random variables with supports $ \left( -\infty ,\infty \right) $ and $r$ be a continuous function. In addition, $A+B$ and $r\left( 2A+B\right)$ are independent. Is there a *non-constant* function $r$ and random variables $A$ and $B$ that satisfy these conditions?

Comment: try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest

Comment: Will: why do you suggest (the second page of) math.stackexchange.com for this question? I don't yet see the answer - instinct tells me it should be no, but I would be glad to see it answered here. Am I missing something obvious? 

Comment: Will, thank you for the link, I looked there but did not find anything related to my question.

James, thanks, I too think the answer should be "no" but no luck proving it.